# jQuery .find('input:checked') not matching elements with checked="checked" HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple code
HTML:

```
<div class="currenciesRow">
     <input name="myChkbox" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
     <input name="myChkbox" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

JS:

```
var objChecked = $('.currenciesRow').find('input:checked');
console.log(objChecked.length);
```

Somehow when I'm call this on `document.ready()` it's returning 0, but when I'm call this `.on('change', function(){...})` its returning proper value

Comment: http://jsbin.com/mamusido/1/edit — I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Directly use as `$('.currenciesRow:checked');`

Comment: @AmitAgrawal That is not the same as what OP want.

Answer (score -1):

remove your "input" into your

```
 .find();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5BgVQ/2/)

Comment: That works … but so does the code in the original question, so you haven't solved any problem here.